# Conditional `DependentUpon` depending on existence of file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, msbuild

I have a shared project targeting multiple platforms with some files being dedicated to certain platforms. These can be ordinary C# classes or markup files.

I want to have these files grouped under their respective `.cs` file in the former, and their `.xaml` file in the latter case.

Along with the `xaml.cs` some `.xaml` files might also have an additional `.cs` file. These are currently hardcoded to depend upon their `.xaml` counterpart. With the following configuration I get the desired result for markup files:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Update="**\*Android.cs">
       <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy(%(Filename)).Replace('.Android', '.xaml'))</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>
 </ItemGroup>
```

Namely:

```
- Page.xaml
  - Page.cs
  - Page.xaml.cs
  - Page.Android.cs
```

However, If I configure the project to group files under the `.cs` files as well, I get the following result for markup:

```
- Page.xaml
  - Page.cs
     - Page.Android.cs
  - Page.xaml.cs
```

This is expected but undesirable.

Can I define some sort of conditional to avoid this to happen?

EDIT:

For clarification, it is a `.shproj` with the following configuration:

```
<Compile Update="**\*Android.cs">
  <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy(%(Filename)).Replace('.Android', '.xaml'))</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="**\*Android.cs">
  <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy(%(Filename)).Replace('.Android', '.cs'))</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

In the `.porjitems` file `.xaml.cs` files are excplicitly configured as follows:

```
<Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Pages\SomePage.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>SomePage.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

This configuration results in the following out put for classes/markup respectively:

```
- Page.xaml
  - Page.cs
     - Page.Android.cs
  - Page.xaml.cs

- Class.cs
  - Class.Android.cs
```

while the following is which i try to achieve:

```
- Page.xaml
  - Page.cs
  - Page.Android.cs
  - Page.xaml.cs

- Class.cs
  - Class.Android.cs
```

Comment: When you say "... I configure the project to group files under the .cs files ...", what change are you making? Do you add an `Update` for `**\*.cs` files? Can you share the configuration change you are making?

Comment: I notice the result on your side seems to have structure, whether you get the results? And what is the type of the project on your side?

Comment: @JonathanDodds I attached the configuration, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT It is a `.shproj`, though the way I see it, a Class Library behaves exactly the same.

Comment: `**\*Android.cs` will match `Class.Android.cs` and `Page.Android.cs` in both `Update`s. Each `Update` overwrites the prior value of the `DependentUpon` metadata. The last `Update` for `Class.Android.cs` sets `Class.cs`, and for `Page.Android.cs` sets `Page.cs` -- as you have observed.

Answer (score 0):

**The issue with the current code:**

`**\*Android.cs` will match `Class.Android.cs` and `Page.Android.cs` in both `Update`s.

Each `Update` overwrites the prior value of the `DependentUpon` metadata. The last `Update` for `Class.Android.cs` sets `Class.cs`, and for `Page.Android.cs` sets `Page.cs` -- as you have observed.

**Solutions:**

One solution is to just explicitly configure all the files.

```xml
  <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Pages\Page.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Page.xaml</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Pages\Page.Android.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Page.xaml</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Pages\Page.xaml.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Page.xaml</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Class.Android.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Class.cs</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
```

Or alternatively

```xml
  <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Pages\Page.cs" />
  <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Pages\Page.Android.cs" />
  <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Pages\Page.xaml.cs" />
  <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Class.Android.cs" />

  <DependsOnPage Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Pages\Page.cs" />
  <DependsOnPage Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Pages\Page.Android.cs" />
  <DependsOnPage Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Pages\Page.xaml.cs" />

  <DependsOnClass Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Class.Android.cs" />

  <Compile Update="@(DependsOnPage)">
    <DependentUpon>Page.xaml</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Include="@(DependsOnClass)">
    <DependentUpon>Class.cs</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
```

This is manual maintenance but if the project doesn't change often, it may be acceptable.

A solution where manual intervention is not needed is possible but is a bit tricky. MSBuild has two phases: evaluation and execution. The `DependentUpon` metadata needs to be set during evaluation of the IDE UI won't reflect it. Targets are not 'run' until the execution phase so all the logic for the `DependentUpon` metadata must be contained in 'top level' `ItemGroup` and `PropertyGroup` elements.

I'll try to update this answer later with a working example.